# Use a variable for a datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to doing something in jquery.
This is a part of my jquery:

```
console.log(tableid);
var table = $('"#'+tableid+'"').DataTable();
```

tableid = "Data-user1"
table is null....
but when i put table = $("#Data-user1").DataTable() it works. Whats wrong?

Comment: `tableid = "foo"; '>>"#'+tableid+'"<<'` - what does the JavaScript Console say this evaluates to? In the case of "foo" the quotes are part of JavaScript syntax denoting the string literal. The string value itself (which is simply 3 characters: foo) does not have the quotes. Compare this to the constructed string (above I added additional marking characters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this?

```
console.log(tableid);
var table = $('#' + tableid).DataTable();
```

Comment: thanks. It works. Sorry because of the noob question :)

Answer (score 2):

Because how you're initializing the datatable is incorrect. You don't need to explicitly quote quotes in the selector; you just need to concatenate the strings like this:

```
var table = $("#" + tableid).DataTable();
```

That should work.

Answer (score 1):

ID Selector correct format -> $(“#id”)

Description: Selects a single element with the given id attribute.

```
var table = $('#' + tableid).DataTable();
```

Take a look at documentation: https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/